# Converting Date to number of Years

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck on a problem on an assignment where I need to change the date to the number of years:

Create a query that will show those employees that left Auntie B's in 2014.

In your output show the people id, hire date, term date and years employed.

Title this last column `Years Employed`.

Your output should look like the following:

```
PeopleID HireDate   TermDate   Years Employed

   1016 2010-06-22 2014-01-15               4
   1029 2010-02-10 2014-02-05               4
```

This is my code:

```
select PeopleId, HireDate,TermDate
from WORKERS 
where TermDate like '%2014%'
 floor(datediff('2010-06-22','2014-01-15', TermDate) / 365) as 'Years Employed'
```

Comment: Assuming your `HireDate` and `TermDate` columns are `date` data types, you should be filtering using date values, such as `where TermDate >= '20140101' and TermDate < '20150101'` which will run a lot faster than converting the date to a `varchar` string, then searching the entire string for `2014`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF()` :

```
SELECT W.*,
       DATEDIFF(YEAR, W.HireDate, W.TermDate)
FROM WORKERS W
WHERE TermDate > '2013-12-31' AND TermDate < '2015-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

`datediff` needs `day` as 1st argument, like this:

```
select 
  PeopleId, 
  HireDate,
  TermDate,
  floor(datediff(day, HireDate, TermDate) / 365) as [Years Employed]
from WORKERS 
where year(TermDate) = 2014
```

Comment: Using functions within your `where` is very bad practice and will cause SQL Server to ignore any relevant indexes on that column: https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/sql-server-query-optimization-sargable-functions/

Comment: You made your point, **but** you did not say what is the alternative. Will you post a more efficient solution for this problem **without using functions** and explain why it is more efficient?

Comment: Quite simply, you do not alter the value in the column but compare it, such as: `where TermDate >= '20140101' and TermDate < '20150101'`, as is explained in the linked article.

Comment: Great, you change 1 comparison with 2!

Comment: Yes, but 2 comparisons that SQL Server is smart enough to apply in one pass of an index on the `TermDate` column, which is ***significantly*** faster than applying the `year` function to every value in the column and checking if the result is `2014`.  It would seem you need to do some reading up on what makes for an efficient SQL Server query.  I would recommend starting with the concept of SARGability which is explained in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: In addition, your solution also doesn't account for leap years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189810/discussion-between-iamdave-and-forpas).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  PeopleId, 
  HireDate,
  TermDate,
  SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,HireDate,TermDate )) / 365.0 AS YEARS_EMPLOYEED
from WORKERS 
where year(TermDate) = 2014
```

here is a good tutorial on how it works:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Answer (score -1):

## A lot of answers here are telling you to just use the `datediff` in years but that may not be what you actually want to do, due to the way `datediff` works.

`datediff` does not calculate the number of complete or even partial periods between the given start and end time.  It calculates the number of *period boundaries crossed.*

What this means is that for all of these calculations:

```
select datediff(year,   '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
      ,datediff(month,  '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
      ,datediff(day,    '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
      ,datediff(hour,   '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
      ,datediff(minute, '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
      ,datediff(second, '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

you would return the value `1` even though there is only 3 milliseconds difference between the two dates, just as:

```
select datediff(year,   '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2019-12-31 23:59:59.997')
```

would also return `1`, even though the period is just 3 milliseconds short of 2 full years.

Due to this, you need to select a smaller period to aggregate across and divide that into a yearly granularity to get your desired value.  Personally I use the number of hours in an *average* year, which will take leap years into account.

Per your examples given, you can return either:

```
select datediff(hour, '2010-06-22', '2014-01-15') / 8766 as WholeYears     -- 3
      ,datediff(hour, '2010-06-22', '2014-01-15') / 8766.0 as DecimalYears -- 3.567419
```

---

It does seem however, that whoever set your assignment is not aware of the above, as they think there is 4 years difference between June 2010 and January 2014 which is incorrect by any measure.

Comment: Where is the WHERE... part?

Comment: `select datediff(day, '2010-06-22', '2014-01-15') / 8766 as WholeYears     
      ,datediff(day, '2010-06-22', '2014-01-15') / 8766.0 as DecimalYears `

Why are you dividing by 8766? if you run that exact query it will return 0 or 0.148642.

Comment: @K.Madden  Ah, typo.  Should have been `hour` instead of `day`

Comment: @iamdave No problem! Was just confused and was starting to question my maths!

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but still cannot see any answer!

Comment: @forpas  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  The OP has come here with a question about an assignment they have to do and specifically asked about finding the number of years between two dates.  That third code block contains how to get a more accurate number of years between two dates.  If the OP can take what I have written and apply it to their assignment, rather than simply copy and paste, they will develop their understanding and be able to apply this knowledge to different situations in the future.

Comment: Keyword in OP's original - "assignment". A student won't learn much if the complete answer is given.

Comment: @forpas  The difference is that not *every* answer needs a complete working script to be a useful answer.  Sometimes it is easiest to provide one as an explanation, other times not.  I think you need to calm down and ask yourself why you are taking this website so seriously.  A student has asked a question and you are clearly very annoyed that I have provided a detailed explanation on the nuances of the functions others are recommending, which if not considered can cause problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @Start DATE ='2010-06-22'
DECLARE @Term DATE = '2014-01-15'

SELECT @Start,@Term,DATEPART(YEAR,@Term)-DATEPART(YEAR,@Start) AS [Years Employed]
```

OR

```
SELECT @Start,@Term,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Start,@Term) AS [Years Employed]
```

Personally, I don't agree that a hire in June 2010 and a term in January 2014 counts as four years, but that isn't my call.